# validates using Proc

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I remove the || statement below this will work. Any ideas why?
I want it to validate only on categories other than "social" and "news"

```
 validates :image, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |a| a.category != "social" || a.category != "news" }
```

Comment: Common mistake when translating ordinary speech to computer language. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737894/in-ruby-why-is-working-while-isnt-in-my-sample-code#comment18878933_13737894

Comment: Oh, and use `proc {|a| ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate on categories that's not 'social' and not 'news', you will need

`validates :image, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |a| a.category != "social" && a.category != "news" }`

Answer (score 1):

SeanLi has given you a correct revision, but allow me to supplement it with some deeper logical understanding.

The confusion here would probably be cleared up by a quick study of [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). These are the rules for distributing negations (NOTs) over conjunctions (ANDs) and disjunctions (ORs). Using Ruby syntax:

"Neither `p` nor `q`" can be written, equivalently, as either `!(p || q)` or `!p && !q`.

Meanwhile, "Not both `p` and `q`" / "Either `not-p` or `not-q`" can be written, equivalently, as either `!(p && q)` or `!p || !q`.

However, as their English renderings make clear, the first pair means something different (is logically distinct from) the second pair.

To risk belaboring the obvious, this fact can be applied to your case by recognizing the equivalence of `!(p == q)` and `p != q`.